# 404 Error when installing stuff on Ubuntu Bash Shell Windows 10

Tags: command-line, bash

I get a 404 error when accessing `security.ubuntu.com/<other stuff>` when I'm trying to install `gcc` and `build-essential` on the Windows 10 Ubuntu bash shell. I'm not sure why this is happening, and any help would be appreciated.

edit: I went to ubuntu security site, and check out where the file that the bash is looking for should be, it just straight up doesn't exist. What now?

[image: bash shell output]

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by a Windows app that blocks networking requests like an anti-malware, firewall, or anti-virus software.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not done `sudo apt update` before attempting to install anything. Thus your package lists are out of date, and contain old versions. linux-libc-dev version 4.15.0-29.31 is a old version, and 4.15.0-45.48 is current version.

Old versions of packages are removed from the mirrors, to save space.

Run `sudo apt update; sudo apt install linux-libc-dev`